# Firebase Database Unity offline support

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unity-application-block

I am building a chat system using firebase database in unity, but unlike all other platforms I was not able to find an offline support for database in unity. Is there any way by which we can enable the offline support?

Comment: are you sure this is about "Unity3d", and not "Unity"?

Comment: its actually about "Unity" in general but couldn't find that tag over there